# Accessing events from interface contract - Event doesn't exist in this contract

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have a contract that calls an event declared in a solidity interface.

I'd like to know how to listen to that event from Web3

```
import "../interfaces/Event.sol";
contract MyContract is ISEvents { 

 function emitEvent(uint32 operatorShare) external returns (bytes32 ID)
{
     emit myEvent(data);
}
}
```

Interface file

```
interface ISEvents {.
    event myEvent(
        uint256 adata
    );
}
```

web3 snippet

```
// MyContract is the web3 instance of MyContract
Myevent =MyContract.events.myEvent()
Myevent.on('data', eventcallback );
```

This returns:  Event "myEvent" doesn't exist in this contract.

What's the way to listen to myEvent from web3. Should i deploy the instance file ? Do i have to declare the event inside my contract for accessing it externaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to declare the event inside your contract for accessing it externally.

As an example, consider the ERC20 smart-contract's solidity code at https://bscscan.com/address/0x2170Ed0880ac9A755fd29B2688956BD959F933F8#code

It contains the following declared events :

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
```

To intercept these events from your web3 javascript/nodejs code you can do the following :

```
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/');
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey)
    const account2 = wallet.connect(provider);

    const factory = new ethers.Contract(
    '0x2170Ed0880ac9A755fd29B2688956BD959F933F8',
    [
        'event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value)',
        'event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value)',
    ],
    account2
    );

    factory.on('Transfer', async (from, to, value) => {
        console.log('transfer ' + from + ' ' + to + ' ' + value)
    })

    factory.on('Approval', async (owner, spender, value) => {
        console.log('approval ' + owner + ' ' + spender + ' ' + value)
    })
```

This is for an ERC20 (BEP20) smart contract deployed on the Binance Smart Chain but this is exactly the same for the Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but isn't it breaking the purpose of creating interfaces? My interface contains around 15 events shared in 3 different contract.

Comment: I think not, but you should give it a try. I think that you you will have then to declare 3 ethers.Contract() to get access to these 3 different contracts' events.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE your ABI and CONTRACT address on Web3.js variables.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured that one myself If someone falls on the same issue using Solidity Interface to have a central place to declare our events and share it between your different contracts.

Since the event is declared in the Instance file and because Javascript cannot resolve the reference in the Parent Contract you have to use the ABI file of that Solidity Instance to fetch the reference of your events.

Answer (score 0):

Simply save full contract Abi to a file and load this file on your js code.

code snippet:

```
let contractAbi = require('./yourABI.json');
let contract = new web3js.eth.Contract(contractAbi, tokenAddress);
```